# how to set a context to NSString drawAtPoint?

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-graphics

I currently working on encapsulation many `[NSString drawAtPoint:withFont:]` function calls to a method so that I could draw lots of strings by a single call, but how can I tell the method where to draw these strings?

What if I pass a `CGContextRef` to it, how to set a `CGContextRef` as current context?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you need this part of code:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne it was long ago and even I can say now what maybe I misunderstood question. He need to create context (for example this _ CGBitmapContextCreate_) and then push it as John Lemberger suggested. - With this approach you can have image at any moment.

Answer (score 6):

On iOS 4 and later, wrap the NSString drawAtPoint calls with UIGraphicsPushContext(context) and UIGraphicsPopContext().

[See accepted answer for "Using NSStrings drawAtPoint method in place of CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319873/using-nsstrings-drawatpoint-method-in-place-of-cgcontextshowglyphsatpoint-probl)