# NSString drawInRect set context

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I draw some image in background. Sometimes my app crashes with strange error:

> function signature specialization < Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of MyApp.

I checked all crashes, and I get all of them on methods that do not use context. One of them draw text. How can I specify context to draw text?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1.0)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
// some code
str.drawInRect(CGRectMake(floor(10 * scaleFactor), yOffset, size.width, floor(60 * scaleFactor)), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
// code
let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

#### Edit

I do not found any method to draw text in specific context. I use `UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)` before draw text and `UIGraphicsPopContext()` after. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402637/820795

Comment: Do you use this drawing algorithm in background (thread other than main thread )?

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne Yes. It works in background. And I expect that system generate own context while I drawing on it. So when new context created it push in stack. I think I can use `UIGraphicsPushContext`, but anyway no guaranty that it not crash. Also it can crash before I use pop context. So it will be great to draw text in specific context.

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne why? Documentation says that "This function may be called from any thread of your app."

Comment: Ok yeah it seems like you can call it from aby thread. So, what is the error or crash log that you get ?

Comment: This is `CGContext`. `CGBItmapContext` subtype of `CGContext` as I know.

Comment: I do not have normal logs with Swift :( You can see in question the only error that I get. Other info does not have any sense.

Comment: Drawing in a background thread is thread-safe. But that doesn't mean that _your_ code is thread-safe. You are saying things like `str.drawInRect(CGRectMake(floor(10 * scaleFactor), yOffset, size.width, floor(60 * scaleFactor)), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)`. How do we know that you have obtained those variables in a thread-safe way?

Comment: @matt this is local variables

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that this has anything to do with drawing. The "function signature specialization" arises when there's a mistake in the Swift APIs where Objective-C needs to pass a nil parameter value to Swift, but the Swift version of this parameter is not typed as an Optional.

Comment: This error happens really seldom. I can't get it on my device, I only see crashes in Crashlytics.

Comment: I didn't say it happened often, I said that this was the sort of thing that caused it.

Comment: @matt I'm curious where you read that information about "function signature specialization."  Is that documented somewhere in the Swift library docs?  Maybe part of llvm?  I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: @JAL Could alternatively be a threading issue, not sure. Solution might be to surround everything with a GCD block so can't run simultaneously on two thread.

Comment: @matt Sorry, I wasn't clear.  Unrelated to the question, how did you know that "'function signature specialization' arises when there's a mistake in the Swift APIs where Objective-C needs to pass a nil parameter value to Swift, but the Swift version of this parameter is not typed as an Optional."